# Firefox: "Secure Connection Failed" in one profile only. What's the least intrusive way to solve this?

Tags: firefox

After a time period of really bad internet connection, I get "Secure Connection Failed" for all Google sites: `www.google.com`, `drive.google.com`, `accounts.google.com`, `www.youtube.com` etc. My guess would be a corrupted certificate or similar piece of cached data.

I have tried

- [starting into safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode): no success
- [creating a new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles#w_creating-a-profile): works
- [using "Forget About This Site"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/914393): I tried it on Youtube and it seemed to work for a while, but now it doesn't and I can't reproduce it working...
- [clearing the cache (web content only)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache) no success

I made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/SillyFreak/6186d19ba1310ef84b70388987395c64/revisions#diff-db77a12610f559ed81e181f46d9e8813) that contains the diff between working and non-working security info requesting `www.google.com` in the Network tab of the Developer tools. There is a difference, but it doesn't look corrupted.

```
14c14
<       "Common Name (CN):": "www.google.com",
---
>       "Common Name (CN):": "*.google.com",
28,29c28,29
<       "SHA-256 Fingerprint:": "40:20:11:2A:CA:7E:91:BD:6D:8D:B3:9B:D1:C1:77:43:99:CD:07:CF:CF:96:22:23:B0:82:A6:EA:46:02:D9:B9",
<       "SHA1 Fingerprint:": "5F:C0:48:7E:6F:B8:02:ED:FE:46:25:16:BA:80:FA:9B:E3:2E:72:4B"
---
>       "SHA-256 Fingerprint:": "D2:03:D3:51:0A:DC:E0:42:06:77:50:EE:83:04:D8:B5:5E:C8:D3:91:38:86:79:17:CB:D7:68:B3:32:A5:0B:74",
>       "SHA1 Fingerprint:": "5B:E1:DA:24:FE:99:92:FB:D2:AB:A8:DD:E9:49:AF:3A:56:43:F1:B4"
```

I would prefer to keep my profile; is there a more surgical way to remove the offending piece of data?

---

Edit: a cropped screenshot with what I hope is the relevant information:

[image: screenshot]

View certificate opens the following link, which apparently has the certificate encoded in it:

```
about:certificate?cert=MIIJVDCCCDygAwIBAgIQMb4HexqczOACAAAAAHJsYjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBCMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEeMBwGA1UEChMVR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNlcnZpY2VzMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpHVFMgQ0EgMU8xMB4XDTIwMDcwNzA4MDQzOFoXDTIwMDkyOTA4MDQzOFowZjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdvb2dsZSBMTEMxFTATBgNVBAMMDCouZ29vZ2xlLmNvbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IABBa%2Fj7PiwGsn0fvyJ9lwlDv4ZFSUB8qVbSjKdqhGFX%2BVMa7QufwePfG6CWz4FlFwAd2Ys4u8ciMOQgbQNmFQ6JujggbrMIIG5zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwDAYDVR0TAQH%2FBAIwADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUAi8D%2FFIh4Gu1wv0qrE3MO%2BbGbwEwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUmNH4bhDrz5vsYJ8YkBug630J%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%2BCCGdncGh0LmNuggxna2VjbmFwcHMuY26CBmdvby5nbIIUZ29vZ2xlLWFuYWx5dGljcy5jb22CCmdvb2dsZS5jb22CD2dvb2dsZWNuYXBwcy5jboISZ29vZ2xlY29tbWVyY2UuY29tghhzb3VyY2UuYW5kcm9pZC5nb29nbGUuY26CCnVyY2hpbi5jb22CCnd3dy5nb28uZ2yCCHlvdXR1LmJlggt5b3V0dWJlLmNvbYIUeW91dHViZWVkdWNhdGlvbi5jb22CD3lvdXR1YmVraWRzLmNvbYIFeXQuYmUwIQYDVR0gBBowGDAIBgZngQwBAgIwDAYKKwYBBAHWeQIFAzAzBgNVHR8ELDAqMCigJqAkhiJodHRwOi8vY3JsLnBraS5nb29nL0dUUzFPMWNvcmUuY3JsMIIBAgYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSB8wSB8ADuAHUAB7dcG%2BV9aP%2FxsMYdIxXHuuZXfFeUt2ruvGE6GmnTohwAAAFzKIU4BgAABAMARjBEAiA%2F1RAmclL1qeucYAs10G1PNVe3oSLp3j9dAey0vH4kGwIgOf86FMBXuNSU6elhohzYNorQWtnNfhbrzQgwE7ro%2B8gAdQBep3P531bA57U2SH3QSeAyepGaDIShEhKEGHWWgXFFWAAAAXMohTY9AAAEAwBGMEQCIAfqdKWJcw%2FLBM50ehgi%2B6vPKQOHoEf683vRw9QOAmPsAiBkg69Wh9mddhOBpz8RgsiJeqoCGoAk9ZB3lt5JR9MyoTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAKsCNiPdcp%2BMWY3Hn%2BNHanl2awyGEw5fBT2FOLYbjtEQX76eN8tuCNi7bCcHWht0u124AfrBQS0O%2BliQmhZln3myGX42aEelZ9WHBrviI9IPdCtuRxIm12%2FPjtsc9rV90B9etkTnPrm1ou3DdJKCUfailvEAVPQwjOQo0z7sdIB%2FZ9g1I7ixPvOjo6kptM8sEYc9U3ncBROfy%2BfswPfGyS7HqFHOtob3atn8qgFnJD6e4iU081Pmx1UND7eVu7j5YWB94N0Pn8ozcDqmYOCqmlTRSWEyHTO65yi000769BOMuytv9m%2FirYvYXeMHT4TaS%2BIykXiB1xsy%2F0%2F4w8u9A1Q%3D%3D&cert=MIIESjCCAzKgAwIBAgINAeO0mqGNiqmBJWlQuDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBMMSAwHgYDVQQLExdHbG9iYWxTaWduIFJvb3QgQ0EgLSBSMjETMBEGA1UEChMKR2xvYmFsU2lnbjETMBEGA1UEAxMKR2xvYmFsU2lnbjAeFw0xNzA2MTUwMDAwNDJaFw0yMTEyMTUwMDAwNDJaMEIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMR4wHAYDVQQKExVHb29nbGUgVHJ1c3QgU2VydmljZXMxEzARBgNVBAMTCkdUUyBDQSAxTzEwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDQGM9F1IvN05zkQO9%2BtN1pIRvJzzyOTHW5DzEZhD2ePCnvUA0Qk28FgICfKqC9EksC4T2fWBYk%2FjCfC3R3VZMdS%2FdN4ZKCEPZRrAzDsiKUDzRrmBBJ5wudgzndIMYcLe%2FRGGFl5yODIKgjEv%2FSJH%2FUL%2BdEaltN11BmsK%2BeQmMF%2B%2BAcxGNhr59qM%2F9il71I2dN8FGfcddwuaej4bXhp0LcQBbjxMcI7JP0aM3T4I%2BDsaxmKFsbjzaTNC9uzpFlgOIg7rR25xoynUxv8vNmkq7zdPGHXkxWY7oG9j%2BJkRyBABk7XrJfoucBZEqFJJSPk7XA0LKW0Y3z5oz2D0c1tJKwHAgMBAAGjggEzMIIBLzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMBIGA1UdEwEB%2FwQIMAYBAf8CAQAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFJjR%2BG4Q68%2Bb7GCfGJAboOt9Cf0rMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFJviB1dnHB7AagbeWbSaLd%2FcGYYuMDUGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCkwJzAlBggrBgEFBQcwAYYZaHR0cDovL29jc3AucGtpLmdvb2cvZ3NyMjAyBgNVHR8EKzApMCegJaAjhiFodHRwOi8vY3JsLnBraS5nb29nL2dzcjIvZ3NyMi5jcmwwPwYDVR0gBDgwNjA0BgZngQwBAgIwKjAoBggrBgEFBQcCARYcaHR0cHM6Ly9wa2kuZ29vZy9yZXBvc2l0b3J5LzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAGoA%2BNnn78y6pRjd9XlQWNa7HTgiZ%2Fr3RNGkmUmYHPQq6Scti9PEajvwRT2iWTHQr02fesqOqBY2ETUwgZQ%2BlltoNFvhsO9tvBCOIazpswWC9aJ9xju4tWDQH8NVU6YZZ%2FXteDSGU9YzJqPjY8q3MDxrzmqepBCf5o8mw%2FwJ4a2G6xzUr6Fb6T8McDO22PLRL6u3M4Tzs3A2M1j6bykJYi8wWIRdAvKLWZu%2FaxBVbzYmqmwkm5zLSDW5nIAJbELCQCZwMH56t2Dvqofxs6BBcCFIZUSpxu6x6td0V7SvJCCosirSmIatj%2F9dSSVDQibet8q%2F7UK4v4ZUN80atnZz1yg%3D%3D&cert=MIIDujCCAqKgAwIBAgILBAAAAAABD4Ym5g0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwTDEgMB4GA1UECxMXR2xvYmFsU2lnbiBSb290IENBIC0gUjIxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdsb2JhbFNpZ24xEzARBgNVBAMTCkdsb2JhbFNpZ24wHhcNMDYxMjE1MDgwMDAwWhcNMjExMjE1MDgwMDAwWjBMMSAwHgYDVQQLExdHbG9iYWxTaWduIFJvb3QgQ0EgLSBSMjETMBEGA1UEChMKR2xvYmFsU2lnbjETMBEGA1UEAxMKR2xvYmFsU2lnbjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKbPJA6%2BLm8omUVCxKs%2BIVSbC9N%2FhHD6ErPLv4dfxn%2BG07IwXNb9rfF73OX4YJYJkhD10FPe%2B3t%2Bc4isUoh7SqbKSaZeqKeMWhG8eoLrvozps6yWJQeXSpkqBy%2B0Hne%2Fig%2B1AnwblrjFuTosvNYSuetZfeLQBoZfXklqtTleiDTsvHgMCJiEbKjNS7SgfQx5TfC4LcshytVsW33hoCmEofnTlEnLJGKRILzdC9XZzPnqJworc5HGnRusyMvo4KD0L5CLTfuwNhv2GXqF4G3yYROIXJ%2FgkwpRl4pazq%2Br1feqCapgvdzZX99yqWATXgAByUr6P6TqBwMhAo6CygPCm48CAwEAAaOBnDCBmTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH%2FBAUwAwEB%2FzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUm%2BIHV2ccHsBqBt5ZtJot39wZhi4wNgYDVR0fBC8wLTAroCmgJ4YlaHR0cDovL2NybC5nbG9iYWxzaWduLm5ldC9yb290LXIyLmNybDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSb4gdXZxwewGoG3lm0mi3f3BmGLjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAmYFThxxol4aR7OBKuEQLq4GsJ0%2FWwbgcQ3izDJr86iw8bmEbTUsp9Z8FHSbBuOmDAGJFtqkIk7mpM0sYmsL4h4hO291xNBrBVNpGP%2BDTKqttVCL1OmLNIG%2B6KYnX3ZHu01yiPqFbQfXf5WRDLenVOavSot%2B3i9DAgBkcRcAtjOj4LaR0VknFBbVPFd5uRHg5h6h%2Bu%2FN5GJG79G%2BdwfCMNYxdAfvDbbnvRG15RjF%2BCv6pgsH%2F76tuIMRQyV%2BdTZsXjAzlAcmgQWpzU%2FqlULRuJQ%2F7TBj0%2FVLZjmmx6BEP3ojY%2Bx1J96relc8geMJgEtslQIxq%2FH5COEBkEveegeGTLg%3D%3D
```

I'm using Firefox 79.0 (64-bit) on Xubuntu, as packaged by Xubuntu

---

Further information as requested:

`about:config` excerpt:

```
security.OCSP.enabled                   1   
security.OCSP.require                   false   
security.OCSP.timeoutMilliseconds.hard  10000   
security.OCSP.timeoutMilliseconds.soft  2000    
security.ssl.enable_ocsp_must_staple    true    
security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling       true
security.cert_pinning.hpkp.enabled      false
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the certificate information from within Firefox instead of text based information you provided.  Firefox will indicate if the certificate is valid or not which is actually the information we need to help solve your problem.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Comment: @Ramhound is this the information you meant?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: It's odd that there's no error code. You typically get one on e.g. HPKP failures.

Comment: @Bob oh, sorry about that. I'm using Firefox 79.0 (64-bit) on Xubuntu, as packaged by Xubuntu. I also added it to the question

Comment: Given you say it only affects Google, I wonder if you've got a corrupted intermediate certificate saved. Go to your profile folder (e.g. via `about:profiles`) and delete any `cert8.db` or `cert9.db` files to clear them, then try again. For completeness you may also wish to remove `key3.db`/`key4.db` (note that this will delete any client certificates and keys, and may also clear any previously added exceptions).

Comment: Also, please show us (in `about:config`) how you have the `security.OCSP` keys configured. And the value of `security.cert_pinning.hpkp.enabled`.

Comment: I had `cert9` and `key4`, deleting either or both did not make a difference. I added the config values in an edit; these are all default values. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just ot be clear, you deleted the databases while Firefox was closed? I'm about out of ideas for now, so, just for a laugh, try turning `security.OCSP.enabled` off. (Don't forget to enable it again; just trying to narrow it down!) You can also open the Browser Console (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J) and see if anything interesting appears there. Perhaps go to `about:serviceworkers` and unregister them. Failing all that, you could try more detailed logging in `about:networking#logging`, though it can be a pain to read the resulting logs.

Comment: yes, Firefox was closed; I did three runs: delete `cert9.db` only, delete `key4.db` only, delete both once more. I tried your last few suggestions; OCSP & unregistering all serviceworkers didn't do anything. Probably by chance, FF crashed when I tried to look at the Browser Console mid-startup; didn't happen again though. Other than that, nothing extraordinary. Anyway, thanks for taking the time! Guess I'll "refresh" Firefox and re-open all those tabs.

Comment: For future readers: I will keep the old profile around, so if someone is keen on finding the issue, I will be able to try stuff out.